# Play framework WS set cookie

Tags: http, scala, cookies, playframework-2.1

How can I set cookie in WS request?

```
val request = WS.url("http://testurl.com/test.pdf")
```

Is it possible?

I'm using Play version 2.1.1

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe you can pass cookies in request header with name "Cookie".

Comment: as @vitalii said, you can use `WS.url("http://testurl.com/test.pdf").withHeaders("Cookie" -> myCookie)` and AFAIK, Cookies are Base64 encoded

Answer (score 12):

```
WS.url(theurl).withHeaders("Cookie" -> "cookiename=cookieval; name2=val2")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add domain and path to the cookie in the same manner

```
WS.url("http://url.com").withHeaders("Cookie" -> "cookieName=value; domain=url.com; path=/")
```

Comment: Would that be for Set-Cookie rather?

Comment: I don't think thats valid, you are confusing Cookie which is sent by client during request and Set-Cookie which is sent by a server in response.  Cookie only includes values: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie